# Example of a fieldset tag in HTML

Tags: html, fieldset

Does anyone have good examples of how to use a fieldset tag in HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean [`<fieldset>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_fieldset.asp) ?

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
    Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Or possibly [`<frameset>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_frameset.asp) ?

```
<html>
  <frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
    <frame src="frame_a.htm" />
    <frame src="frame_b.htm" />
    <frame src="frame_c.htm" />
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: He most likely meant `fieldset`.

Comment: That would seem more timely. I haven't seen `frameset` in years.

Answer (score 1):

SitePoint [has a picture](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/fieldset) showing proper use of the `fieldset` tag. There's also more details there.